# I want to make this boolean value true when I click this button. And pass it to a function to display something on screen

Tags: android, kotlin

This is the code for the button

```
class NewGame : AppCompatActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_game)
    val results = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView5)
    val results2 = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView6)
    val submit = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button7)
    var hasclicked = false



    submit.setOnClickListener {
        hasclicked = true

    }
    game (result, hasclicked)
```

This is the code for the function

```
fun game(
     result: TextView, hasclicked : Boolean ) {
  



    if (hasclicked == true){
        result.setText("correct")
    }
```

But when I run this and click on the button nothing appears on screen. Can someone help me with this.

Comment: `Is assigned but never accessed` well you're assigning a value to it, `= true`, but are you ever using it ?

Comment: So I want to make something happen when I click this button using a function, So I set this value to true and then send it to the function like game(hasclicked). Inside the function is have it setText to something if this hasclicked value is true. But that doesnt happen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On clicking, you are only assigning **true** to boolean but not calling the **game(result, hasclicked)** function:

It should be like this:

```
submit.setOnClickListener {
    hasclicked = true
    game(result, hasclicked)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**We get this error when we just set a value but do not try using it.**

Here if you see your code, you are setting the value. But, not getting it.

**By accessed it means that you are not getting it. Only setting it.**

You can just choose to ignore it in some cases where it actually make sense,

[image]

What you can do is hover the affected area and press <kbd>Alt</kbd> +  <kbd>Enter</kbd> in "Windows" or <kbd>alt/option/⌥</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> in "Mac", **and chose to suppress it**.

You'll see,

[image]